# Fortran: class in abstract interface

Tags: oop, fortran

Fortran compiler gives me this error message

> Derived type 'method' at (1) is being used before it is defined

but I do not see what can be wrong there. A very simplified code is as follows.

**1.** Main body (not essential for understanding):

```
program fpointers
  use Mrun
  call run()
end program fpointers
```

**2.** Module with types and extended types

```
module Mtypes

  type method
     integer :: basic
  end type method

  type, extends(method) :: advanced
     logical :: option
  end type advanced
end module Mtypes
```

**3.** And finally a module where the error occurs

```
module Mrun

contains
  subroutine run()
    use Mtypes
    implicit none

    abstract interface
       subroutine init_proc(m)
         class(method)                :: m
       end subroutine init_proc
    end interface

    class(method),pointer             :: used_method
    procedure(init_proc), pointer     :: init
    
  end subroutine run
  
end module Mrun
```

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163654/derived-type-is-being-used-before-it-is-defined-in-interface-block and in turn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751195/why-is-the-type-not-accessible

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for pointing in the right direction and for closing the question. Everything is working as intended!